# Как создать интерфейс для поиска приведенный в примере?

Tags: android

Каким образом реализуется такой интерфейс?

[image]

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `ToolBar` с `SearchView`. Подробное описание можете найти в [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Пример добавления `SearchView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return true;
}
```